# Eclipse Android Plugin -- libncurses.so.5

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

I am struggling mightily with installing ADT (Android Dev Tools) on Eclipse in Fedora 16 OS, 64-bit.

Eclipse itself is running fine.

As instructed, I first installed the regular Android SDK, the OS-level toolkit. That went smoothly and I was able to use the Android app within the tools dir.

In Eclipse, it was a little more difficult because I first had to install GWT or google-related tools, which required a core Eclipse Indigo update of WST. Finally, the ADT install reported success.

However, every time when opening Eclipse, it gives me a multitude of popups regarding libncurses.so.5 and the following log:

```
[2012-04-04 02:06:35 - adb] /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2012-04-04 02:06:35 - adb] 'adb version' failed!
/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2012-04-04 02:06:35 - adb] Failed to parse the output of 'adb version':
Standard Output was:

Error Output was:
/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[2012-04-04 02:06:35 - adb] /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2012-04-04 02:06:35 - adb] 'adb version' failed!
/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2012-04-04 02:06:35 - adb] Failed to parse the output of 'adb version':
Standard Output was:

Error Output was:
/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I do try to open Android SDK Manager (under Window), the plugin does open but the window has no close button anywhere (unlike the same one at the OS-level, which also looks the same) so the only way to get out of it is to find the Eclipse PID and kill it.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

This solved the problem entirely:

```
yum install ncurses-libs.i686 libstdc++.i686 libgcc.i686
```

Comment: And for ubuntu: `apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6`

(lib32gcc1 is pulled in as a dependency)

Comment: @vsekhar, thanks! I was trying this on debian 64bit and those were the packages I needed.

Comment: Arch: `pacman -Syv lib32-libstdc++5 lib32-ncurses lib32-gcc-libs` :)

Comment: quite amazed how after I had to switch to 64bits to compile android 4.2, I have to install a whole lot of 32 bits versions of libraries to have it actually work ...

Answer (score 60):

This is happening because Android SDK is a 32bit application and require some 32bit shared libraries,

I had same issue on Ubuntu 64 bits, and fixed with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: This is overkill by about 40 libs and 240MB. See the three specific libs needed in foampile's answer

Comment: You are ok, so mi upvote is for your comment. But it solves main problem and that was solution I used. I just can't do apt-get install libncurses because is already installed.

Comment: you aren't overwriting your existing ncurses, you are merely adding lib32ncurses5 (and friends)

Comment: @sourcerebels Thanks Buddy, this fixed my missing libncurses problem for BitchX in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS :)

Comment: You can just `sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386` to install the required library - much lighter than `ia32-libs`

Comment: Ok. This does the trick on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and I agree, a huge download but it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

Install just libncurses5:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386
```

ia32-libs will install much unnecessary libs.

Comment: Solved it for me. I'm running Debian here.

Answer (score 6):

```
yaourt -S multilib/lib32-ncurses
```

for **ArchLinux**

Comment: @Oin this is the first thread that shows up for "android ncurses 5 so error" so it is relevant for other distros/packaging systems as well.

Comment: I am trying to compile FFMPEG for android. now your command is installing the version 6 of the library though FFMPEG requires it to be version 5 perhaps. How to install version 5 of it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have `libncurses5` installed.
Try

```
rpm --install ncurses-libs
```

Comment: i do have libncurses5

[root@t520 init.d]# yum install ncurses-libs.x86_64
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Package ncurses-libs-5.9-2.20110716.fc16.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: yum install ncurses-libs.i686 libstdc++.i686 libgcc.i686

Answer (score 0):

had similar issue on centos:

> ./adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

did the following:

```
yum install ncurses ncurses-devel ncurses-libs ncurses-libs.i686   ncurses-devel.i686
```

And the issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This [tip from Tim Mattison's blog](http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2011/11/02/how-to-install-googles-android-eclipse-plugin-and-or-adb-on-64-bit-debian-ubuntu/) did it for me under *Debian Wheezy*:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6
```