# Cannot run Android AVD run with Eclipse on Linux

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-virtual-device

I am trying to make my Android AVD run with Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.10.  I created the AVD in eclipse, and now it's not running. This is the output error I receive when I run the AVD:

> Starting emulator for AVD 'My_android-16'
>   - Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/usrdata/Dev/android-sdk-linux//tools/emulator": error=2, No such
>   file or directory

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, latest Eclipse installed.

What I've done:

1. I gave `/tools/emulator chomod 777` permissions.
2. `cp /usrdata/Dev/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator /usrdata/Dev/android-sdk-linux`

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. This is a very valid question

Comment: @ArunAntony You could always suggest an edit to improve it.

Comment: @George I feel the question is very much clear. May be I am a starter on ubuntu and I hit the same roadblock which an expert would never hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following  command on terminal:

`apt-get install ia32-libs`

Ref:http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html#troubleshooting

Comment: @stat30fbliss: This works. I am using Ubuntu 12.10 64bit, Intel Core i3. You might be missing something.

Comment: Sure, understandable.  I am on a Pentium powered Lenovo.  Nothing I tried with the ia32-libs would work for me, but this dudes comment on the accepted answer of this [SO QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005907/eclipse-android-plugin-libncurses-so-5) did the trick.  Just in case, here's the snippet `apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6`

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to install all the ia32 package. You can just use:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6
```

Also, I needed to make a soft link for LibGL.so.1 as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332817/failed-to-load-libgl-so-in-android).

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 ~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib/libGL.so
```