# Error while launching project in android

Tags: android, linux, fedora

I am using Fedora 17 64 bit operation system. I got following error even after installing 32 bit shared library.

```
[2013-03-22 19:19:29 - adb] /usr/src/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2013-03-22 19:19:29 - adb] 'adb version' failed!
/usr/src/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb:
```

error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    [2013-03-22 19:19:29 - adb] Failed to parse the output of 'adb version':

I had tried installing following library but it still didn't work

```
yum install ncurses-libs.i686
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
No package ncurses-libs.i686 available.
Error: Nothing to do

Even After trying following command it didn't work.

yum install ncurses-libs.i686 libstdc++.i686 libgcc.i686
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
updates/metalink                                                                                                                                | 3.6 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                         | 4.6 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                                                                                                              | 7.9 MB     00:24     
No package ncurses-libs.i686 available.
Package libstdc++-4.7.2-2.fc17.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libgcc-4.7.2-2.fc17.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install the ia32-libs package using apt-get::

apt-get install ia32-libs

For more information http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

try this command :

```
yum install ncurses-libs.i686 libstdc++.i686 libgcc.i686
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Android SDK is a 32bit application and require some 32bit shared libraries,

You can  fixed with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

See here : [Android SDK — Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005907/eclipse-android-plugin-libncurses-so-5)

Comment: this command won't work because its rpm base operating system

Answer (score 0):

I am on centos and following dependencies will resolve android build issue

yum install ncurses-libs.i686 libstdc++48.i686 libgcc.i686 zlib.i686