# Android adb error message: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5

Tags: android, adb

I've been trying to execute the simple hello world app from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#Emulator via an emulator and I'm getting this error:

- `/<my path>/platform-tools/adb: cannot execute binary file`

when trying to do:

- `adb install bin/MyFirstApp-debug.apk`

I followed this: [Eclipse Android Plugin -- libncurses.so.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005907/eclipse-android-plugin-libncurses-so-5) with no success.  This is my very first android build and I'm doing it from the command line on Ubuntu 64.

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`?

Comment: Well that's an entirely different issue.  I have, but on a machine connected to the internet.  I did `sudo apt-get -d build-dep ia32-libs` which downloads about 70-80 Mb of data (which seems to be small).

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` on the system where you get `adb: cannot execute binary file` error?

Comment: @AlexP. No, only because I'm attempting to do an offline build

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the jdk version? From cmd type java -version. Also verify you got the right sdks installed in the sdk manager for the emulator image. For instance if your pointing to api 4.1 you need that and associated tools installed to run it in the emulator. If it gets funky go to your .android (not sure on ubuntu) folder and clear out the avd emulator cache and relaunch and recreate the avd. I could be off track because your not using windows and also using the cmd line.

Answer (score -1):

After executing this command 'sudo apt-get install ia32-libs' in terminal, it solve my problem, thanks

Comment: this is not an option anyomore in Ubuntu 20.04