# adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, adb

I'm having some trouble running a Phonegap imported project on my laptop with Debian. 
I have already installed Eclipse and the plug-in for Android and everything seems to work fine until here.
I have added this line to my .bashrc file:

```
   export PATH=${PATH}:/home/s/android-sdks/platform-tools/
```

I choose new Android project from existing file, in Eclipse, and then I load the code of the project. But when I try to execute it, I get this error message:

```
[2013-06-13 18:12:16 - MyProject] Android Launch!
[2013-06-13 18:12:16 - MyProject] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2013-06-13 18:12:16 - MyProject] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2013-06-13 18:12:16 - MyProject] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at '/home/s/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb' and can be executed.
```

If I try to execute the command: adb server-start in the terminal, I get this message:

```
adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Did I miss something? ADB is right, I do not have the file libncurses.so.5 anywhere on my computer even though I have already installed all the 32-bit compatible libraries (my machine is 64-bit).

Comment: Try this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841490/android-adb-error-message-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libncurses-so-5

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need the 32bits version of `ncurses` package,

```
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5
```

Comment: Also addresses the same error when running NaCL debugger, nacl-gdb.